# Loading dll with c++ explicit load

Tags: c++, winapi, dll, explicit

I'm calling a dll explicitally, and everything works fine... The problem is when i return a value from the function where i am loading de dll (a releasing it) the program stops (it looks like)... It seems something dont let the program proceeds...

My code:

```
xfsManager::StartUp(...)
{
    WORD result=0;

    HINSTANCE hGetProcIDDLL = LoadLibrary("c:\\emvlib\\I_krnfct.dll"); 
    FARPROC lpfnGetProcessID = GetProcAddress(HMODULE (hGetProcIDDLL),EMV_KERNEL_INITIALIZATION); 

    typedef DWORD (__stdcall * pICFUNC)(LPSTR); 

    pICFUNC dllFunction;

    dllFunction = pICFUNC(lpfnGetProcessID); 

    DWORD sTmpRc = 0;
    sTmpRc = dllFunction("something");  
    if(sTmpRc != EMV_OK)
    {
        //NOT OK
    } 
    else
    {
        //OK
    }
    FreeLibrary(hGetProcIDDLL);

    return XFS_OK;   // EXITING
    /*-----------------------------*/
}
```

Thanks a lot for your help.

Cristovao Santos

Comment: Are you certain that the signature `DWORD (__stdcall * pICFUNC)(LPSTR)` correctly matches the DLL function's signature and calling convention?

Comment: I did not explained the best way. The problem is not the call to the dll and the value it returns (because if I send a wrong value as parameter, the function returns the dll error), but when the process exits the function StartUp (in the example) ... The log write immediately after calling this function is not written, but all logs within the StartUp function is written ... And I do not understand why! PS: The signature is all right...

Comment: @user1214476: that behavior is consistent with either: the calling convention is wrong or the DLL function  is corrupting memory somewhere (maybe due to a bad pointer or buffer size passed in).  But those aren't the only possibilities.  If you're using MSVC, make sure that `RTC1` or `/RTCs` is being used in your debug build - that can help detect a mismatched calling convention.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't checking the return values from `LoadLibrary()` or `GetProcAddress()` - are these working?

Maybe you have the DLL name/path or the exported function name wrong. Remember that stdcall functions usually have an "@nn" suffix that corresponds to the size of the parameter list. But that's not always true.

Comment: I did not explained the best way. The problem is not the call to the dll and the value it returns (because if I send a wrong value as parameter, the function returns the dll error), but when the process exits the function StartUp (in the example) ... The log write immediately after calling this function is not written, but all logs within the StartUp function is written ... And I do not understand why!

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use wide characters on your call to LoadLibrary:

```
HINSTANCE hGetProcIDDLL = LoadLibrary(L"c:\\emvlib\\I_krnfct.dll"); /* notice the L */
```

Comment: I did not explained the best way. The problem is not the call to the dll and the value it returns (because if I send a wrong value as parameter, the function returns the dll error), but when the process exits the function StartUp (in the example) ... The log write immediately after calling this function is not written, but all logs within the StartUp function is written ... And I do not understand why!

Comment: ok, so there is a log file that is written to within the DLL function does not appear to work, but the log file writes from the calling function do work.  Is this correct?

Comment: No... In the log file i have the log of StartUp function, but when it returns a value (return XFS_OK;), after that, nothing more appears in the log file... So, i think the function that calls the DLL (StartUp in this case) is still running or doing something... I dont know why...

Comment: if I comment out the line "sTmpRc = dllFunction("something");" all goes well...  :)